# DELETE statement conflicted with REFERENCE constraint

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql, windows-server-2008

Ok, here is a strange one.  I have a routine that goes through and makes several deletions of old data.  Ive had a few people complain about getting the error:

```
 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The DELETE statement conflicted with
 the REFERENCE constraint
```

Looking at my code (im using L2S), i dont see how this is possible.  But ok, lets say it is.  I ask the customer to send me their DB so i can debug it some, one catch: When i hook it up to my SQL server and run the routine, i get no errors.  Everything works & deletes as expected.  This is a SQL 2008 Express instance on Win2008 that the DB originally comes from, and I hook it up to a full SQL 2008 instance.  Are there any differences that would cause such behavior?

Comment: Is your client in the habit of letting their 'pro dba' add triggers and what not to your schema? It's happened to me before and it makes me want to eat my keyboard.

Comment: @Alex, quite possible, but would those triggers still be present when i hook the DB up to my server?

Comment: Hmm, maybe you can ask them if they're sending you the exact db that is running in their environment - including any 'extensions' they may have added. I'm also curious if this is strictly a SQL issue or L2S.. Additionally, could you try to run your code in a debugger but connecting to their db?

Comment: Does the client site have multiple users running this code concurrently?  Could it be a concurrency issue?

Answer (score 1):

Get the client to grab the sql profiler logs and check what sql is running. Compare this with the data in the tables to verify the constraint.